# Why is my /var/log folder 118 GB in size?

Tags: 20.04, log, syslog

I am quite new to the aspects of ubuntu although I know the basics.  My computer is running low on storage and upon inspection, I have found that my /var/log folder is 118 GB big!  I have considered just deleting the logs but I am quite new and it doesn't seem right simply to delete every log, since some programs may not be able to deal with lost log files.  The directory itself is 118 GB, which says to me something is wrong, anyway.  Under the closer inspection of the logging directory here is what I find:

```
root@fateh-Inspiron-13-5378:/var/log# ls -la
total 108917496
drwxrwxr-x  16 root              syslog                 4096 Aug 31 05:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root              root                   4096 Aug  3 09:41 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                  22073 Aug 28 07:34 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                  29184 Jul 26 17:57 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 root              adm                    1734 Aug 27 20:15 apport.log
-rw-r-----   1 root              adm                    1169 Aug 20 09:56 apport.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 root              adm                    1055 Aug 13 15:21 apport.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root              adm                     125 Jul 30 08:30 apport.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root              adm                     124 Jul 29 16:01 apport.log.4.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root              adm                     247 Jul 28 09:49 apport.log.5.gz
drwxr-xr-x   2 root              root                   4096 Aug 31 06:14 apt
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  713367 Aug 31 12:11 auth.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  503808 Aug 24 00:00 auth.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                   71547 Aug 18 05:24 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                   11627 Aug  1 23:36 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-------   1 root              root                 322337 Aug 31 05:26 boot.log
-rw-------   1 root              root                 216534 Aug 24 00:00 boot.log.1
-rw-------   1 root              root                 583044 Aug 18 05:24 boot.log.2
-rw-------   1 root              root                  42659 Aug  4 00:00 boot.log.3
-rw-------   1 root              root                  10452 Aug  2 00:00 boot.log.4
-rw-------   1 root              root                  18801 Jul 27 00:00 boot.log.5
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                 104003 Apr 23 00:33 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw----   1 root              utmp                   1152 Aug 22 11:51 btmp
-rw-rw----   1 root              utmp                      0 Apr 23 00:32 btmp.1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root              root                   4096 Aug 28 14:21 cups
drwxr-xr-x   2 root              root                   4096 Apr  8 08:59 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r--   1 root              adm                   84351 Aug 31 05:26 dmesg
-rw-r--r--   1 root              adm                   87800 Aug 30 18:35 dmesg.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root              adm                   21453 Aug 30 07:28 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root              adm                   21348 Aug 30 06:28 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root              adm                   21403 Aug 29 14:10 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root              adm                   21271 Aug 29 10:48 dmesg.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                 612124 Aug 31 06:15 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                1193854 Jul 31 06:48 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                2049792 Aug 12 10:40 faillog
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                  11453 Aug 22 07:11 fontconfig.log
drwx--x--x   2 root              gdm                    4096 Oct  7  2019 gdm3
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                   1242 Aug 31 05:26 gpu-manager.log
drwxr-xr-x   3 root              root                   4096 Apr 23 00:36 hp
drwxrwxr-x   2 root              root                   4096 Jul 25 08:12 installer
drwxr-sr-x+  3 root              systemd-journal        4096 Jul 25 08:13 journal
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                 5050809 Aug 31 12:07 kern.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm             55699410944 Aug 23 22:50 kern.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                 1525796 Aug 18 05:24 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  188167 Aug  1 23:53 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-rw-r--   1 root              utmp               18704352 Aug 12 10:40 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x   5 root              root                   4096 Aug 12 10:40 libvirt
drwxr-x---   2 www-data          www-data               4096 Aug 24 00:00 lighttpd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root              root                   4096 Sep  5  2019 openvpn
drwxr-xr-x   2 pihole            pihole                 4096 Aug 12 14:15 pihole
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                17216 Aug 31 12:00 pihole-FTL.log
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                89319 Aug 30 06:28 pihole-FTL.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                 2326 Aug 24 00:00 pihole-FTL.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                28126 Aug 23 06:50 pihole-FTL.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                 2113 Aug 31 12:00 pihole.log
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                 6294 Aug 31 05:26 pihole.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                 3967 Aug 30 06:28 pihole.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                 1595 Aug 29 07:11 pihole.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                  510 Aug 28 05:24 pihole.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 pihole            pihole                 2201 Aug 27 05:22 pihole.log.5.gz
drwx------   2 root              root                   4096 Apr 23 00:32 private
drwx------   2 speech-dispatcher root                   4096 Jan 19  2020 speech-dispatcher
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                50371538 Aug 31 12:11 syslog
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm             55744626688 Aug 24 00:00 syslog.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                23788290 Aug 18 05:24 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  669055 Aug  4 00:00 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  163942 Aug  3 00:00 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  158326 Aug  2 00:00 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                  116667 Aug  1 00:00 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm                   81773 Jul 31 00:00 syslog.7.gz
-rw-------   1 root              root                      0 Apr 23 00:33 ubuntu-advantage.log
drwxr-x---   2 root              adm                    4096 Aug  4 00:00 unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                    102 Aug 12 05:33 vbox-setup.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                    102 Aug 11 20:21 vbox-setup.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                    102 Aug 11 14:33 vbox-setup.log.2
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                    102 Aug 11 12:21 vbox-setup.log.3
-rw-r--r--   1 root              root                    102 Aug 11 08:54 vbox-setup.log.4
-rw-rw-r--   1 root              utmp                 153600 Aug 31 05:26 wtmp
```

Where the important logs are:

```
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm             55699410944 Aug 23 22:50 kern.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm             55744626688 Aug 24 00:00 syslog.1
```

as well as some other not so big ones.  What can be wrong?  Should I just clean the files with `cat /dev/null > kern.log.1` and `cat /dev/null > syslog.1` or is there a deeper problem with these logs?

Comment: I think that there might be a bigger problem underneath. My guess is that there might be a device which logs on and of a lot, or that the device is booting a lot. Look at the logs and see if some pattern emerge

Comment: @ofirule You were right, there is this message repeating over and over in both syslog.1 and kern.log.1: `Aug 23 21:53:38 fateh-Inspiron-13-5378 kernel: [ 7917.340997] [EXFAT] sector_read: out of range error! (sec = 851524006400)` over and over every second.

Comment: So it's a filesystem issue, `fsck` might help. See: https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/

Comment: Once you resolve whatever is filling the logs, read `man logrotate logrotate.conf`.

Comment: @ofirule (or anyone else), can I use tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux if I only have one partition?    I wrote "df /boot/grub/" and read "/dev/nvme0n1p3". Next, I wrote "umount /dev/nvme0n1p3" and read  "umount: /: umount failed: Operation not permitted."

Comment: If you have only one partiotion it means it's the root partiotion. Read the part called "How to Run fsck on Linux Root Partition" in the same link